# How to resolve null return in Laravel query?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Given my Models `Person` and `Student`. Now, one of my controller is doing this:

```
$person_id = \App\Models\Person::insertGetId(['name' => $request->name, ...]);
\App\Models\Student::create(['person_id' => $person_id, ...]);
$student = \App\Models\Student::where('person_id', $person_id)->first();
dd($student);
```

During execution, everything has been save but **My problem is why i am receiving null on die and dump?**

By the way, my `student` tables' `primary` and `foreign` key is the `person_id` column.

**Edit**

```
class Student extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['section', 'current_year'];//there are other attribute here which I didn't show because I am using mobile

    public function person(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Person', 'person_id', 'id');
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: So, to be clear, you save a person, and receive a person_id, you save a student, and he has this person_id, but you cannot find the student using this person_id? Are you sure your new student contains this person_id?

Comment: Yes, My student table has been populated with person_id. I don't know why I was not able to retrieve.

Comment: Can you show us the Student model?:)

Comment: What's happening in `\App\Models\Person::insertGetId()` ?

Comment: you are missing `person_id` in fillable.

Comment: @Repox sir it returns a person id.

Comment: @AlexanderPaudak Either your `insertGetId()` does indeed **not** return the expected ID or your ` \App\Models\Student::create()` does not insert what you expect. You could verify this by dumping the returned result from the create method: `dd(\App\Models\Student::create(['person_id' => $person_id, ...]))`

Comment: Sir @TsaiKoga thank you very much. Is it mean that even a foreign id must be included on fillable?

Comment: yes, so you can use create with the foreign_key, or you can use relationship `create` method without foreign_key.

Comment: So to get back to my first question:NO, it did not save a student with the correct person_id...

Comment: sir @RobBiermann but when I check in the db it was successfully persited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `person_id` in `$fillable` property:

```php
protected $fillable = ['section', 'current_year', 'person_id'];
```